# Subdomain creation for api deployment

Tags: api, networking, deployment, dns

I am new to domain and its operation.

Lets say,

I got a public domain def.xyz

And I want to deploy my api for which I need a domain like api.def.xyz

Can anybody help me how can I create such a subdomain?

Comment: There's not much context to give a good answer! Basically you'll have to make api.def.xyz to resolve to an IP, that's the DNS part. Then you'll have to handle the webserver configuration on the server side. What do you already have?

Comment: @chocopoche : Thanks for the reply. So no need to buy the subdomain. One question,
How we can resolve the api domain until unless it is register somewhere publically ?

Comment: If you don't own a domain and want to do local dev, you can locally resolve any domain you want. For instance on a linux box, adding "127.0.0.1 def.xyz api.def.xyz" will locally resolve the said domain to localhost.

Comment: @chocopoche Completely agree for local set up(changes in hosts file).
My webserver can resolve the domain name. My question is ,
If I am passing a request api.def.xyz , how it will resolve publically ?
If we are giving request def.xyz , then as this domain is mapped to a public IP , the public hosts web server will listen the request.

Comment: Well, if you own a domain, you should go the DNS settings (assuming your registrar provides DNS) and, for instance, add a CNAME of api.def.xyz to def.xyz. By doing so your subdomain will resolve to the same IP as the main one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created one CNAME on GoDaddy portal and I could able to use the subdomain.